# Connect generic operator <T> with FunctionConstructor

Tags: generics, typescript

I have TS function, which deserialize JSON into some type/object. You give it a constructor function of the type and it tries to reconstruct that type from JSON.

It looks like this.

```
export function deserializeJSON<T>(JSONString: string, type?: FunctionConstructor, ...
```

I would like to express, that argument `type: FunctionConstructor` is constructor from type `<T>`, is that achieavable with some expression?

### UPDATE

Example call of `deserializeJSON`

```
const serializedDate = JSON.stringify(new Date);
const deserializedDate = deserializeJSON<Date>(serializedDate, Date);
```

### EDIT

I've just find out, that `FunctionConstructor` means *constructor of Function*, so it's better to mark argument `type` as `type: Function`, since all constructors are functions, but then I cannot instantiate `new type` without casting type to `<any>`. I would like express something like `<T>.constructor`.

### EDIT

I've defined interface:

```
interface Constructor<T> extends Function{
    new (): T;
    new (...args: Array<any>): T;
    (...args: Array<any>): T;
    prototype: T;
}
```

Which is basically generic newable `Function`, but this type is *"...not assignable to parametr of type DateConstructor"* or any other type constructors, so It's better to stay with `type: Function`, because it accepts all constructors.

Comment: I guess this is not possible directly with this type. How are you calling this function, can you put an example of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Answering my own question.</sub>

This interface need more tests, but it seems to work:

```
interface Constructor<T> extends Function {
    new (): T;
    new (...args: Array<any>): T;
    prototype: T;
}
```